# How to get a raw json as a parameter

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I wanna get a raw json string from my client in my WebAPI application.

I tried it like this :

```
    public string Get([FromBody]string rawjson)
    {


    }
```

I use Google Chrome Rest Console to try my methods first. I add my json content to RAW body and then send a get request.I put a breakpoint on my method to see if i can get the raw json data however, method invokes but rawjson comes as null. I've also tried put but that didn't work either.

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you invoking this method?

Comment: The modelbinder will always try to convert the incoming json to the model you define. Since the json you receive is probably not a single string with key `rawjson`, it is returning null since it can't bind to that key. *If* you can do what you want, it will be by overriding some internal default behaviour. I have no idea what it would be exactly though.

Comment: @su8898 As i said from Chrome's rest console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` methods cannot have Request Body and as such cannot parse values using `[FromBody]`. Please use the `POST` method.

Comment: I just figured that out right now. Thanks. However, i am currently using a post method with same parameter already so i tried PUT and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the rawJson parameter type to Stream you will recieve anything that is posted on your service as as stream and than you can just read that stream to string

Comment: have you tried reading it from HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream and recieving no patameters ?